# Are there any rules as for what derived path can look like?

Tags: pda, seed, address, solana-keygen

For my application I need  to generate new addresses constanly. I want to do it via mnemonic phrases because it'll allow me to restore a private key of an address if I lose it.
I need to generate addresses for SOL, as well as for tokens.

There're multiple patterns I've encountered so far:

```
1) "m/44'/501'/" + index +"'/0'"

2) "m/44'/60'/0'/0/" + i

3) "m/44'/61'/0'/0/" + i

4) "m/44'/0'/0'/0/" + i
```

Can a derivation path be anything? Is there any difference between them?

If I create a **completely random** derivation path, store it somewhere, of course, and then use it in my application, will it work fine regardless of the fact how much random it may be?

```
 "m/123'/45'/999'/73/" + i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it could be anything, but it probably won't be supported by any wallets or tools.

The derivation path like `m/44'/501'/0'/0"` defines a tree to follow from a seed to the actual key, so typically you use one master key and then derive a child key by following the path.  In the case of Solana, `44'` means BIP-44, and `501'` looks like `SOL`, so it's meant to look like the Solana "domain".

Each derivation path will generate a different key in the end. You probably want to stay with `44'` to start, and then feel free to experiment!

There's some nice reading about hierarchical derivation at https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/hd-wallets

Comment: How is `501' looks like SOL`?

Comment: Can it also have an arbitrary length: `"m/44'/60'/0'/0/0'/0'/0'/0'/0'/0'/35/99/123"`? And `"m/44'/60'/999`?

Comment: Yep, looks like it works! I tried `solana-keygen pubkey 'prompt://?full-path=m/44/2017/0/1/0/0/0/0/0'` as a test

Comment: and if you look at `501` as leetspeak, it spells "SOL". "S" = "5", "O" = "0", and "L" = "1"